# How to use an external, static data file in a script hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Python script hosted on Google App Engine to access Twitter API and store the results.

I have a static csv file (on my local machine) that contains the name of all the twitter accounts that I want to collect data from.

How to make this file accessible to my script hosted on Google App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static CSV should be uploadable the same as any of your other python source files.  Note, do *not* upload it as a [`static`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) file -- Those generally serve from a different place and your code does not have access to them<sup>1</sup>.

To open/read the static CSV, you'll want to use a relative path. e.g.  If your directory looks like this:

```
foo
 | - script.py
bar
 | - data.csv
```

Then to read `data.csv` from `script.py`, you'd do something like:

```
import os
data_csv_filename = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'bar', 'data.csv')
with open(data_csv_filename) as data_csv_file:
    ...
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>You could alternatively set it as "application_readable" in `app.yaml` if you actually want to serve the csv file as well as have your application read the data...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with the inconvenience of uploading your code every time you make a change to your CSV file, you could maintain it as a Google Sheet, one value per cell.  Publish it to web.  Then, read it into your app like this:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

csv_url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<key>/export?format=csv'

csv_response = urlfetch.fetch(csv_url, allow_truncated=True) 

if csv_response.status_code == 200:
  row_list = csv_response.content.split('\n')
  for row in row_list:
    item_list = row.split(',')

    do stuff
```